Question About Continuous and Linear Function on $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ - Theorem 4.5.1 from Measure Theory by Donald Cohn
Background
I am self-studying Donald Cohn's Measure Theory second edition. I got stuck on a step of the proof of Theorem 4.5.1. Here is the theorem:

Theorem$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $p$ satisfy $1\leq p<+\infty$, and let $q$ be defined by $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. If $p=1$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, or if $1<p<+\infty$ and $\mu$ is arbitrary, then the operator $T$ defined above is an isometric isomorphism of $L^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ onto $(L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu))^*$.


Proof$\quad$ Since we know that $T$ is an isometry (Proposition 3.5.5), we need only show that it is surjective.
Let $F$ be an arbitrary element of $(L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu))^*$. First suppose that $\mu(X)<+\infty$ and that $p$ satisfies $1\leq p<+\infty$. We define a function $\nu$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ by means of the formula $\nu(A)=F(\langle\chi_A\rangle)$. If $\{A_k\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathscr{A}$ and if $A=\bigcup_kA_k$, then the dominated convergence theorem implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\chi_A-\sum_{k=1}^n\chi_{A_k}\right\|_p$. Since $F$ is continuous and linear, this implies that $F(\langle\chi_A\rangle)=\sum_k^{\infty}F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle)$ ....

In this proof, the notation $\langle f\rangle$ is the coset in $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ to which $f$ belongs. In the case of $1\leq p<+\infty$, $\langle f\rangle$ consists of the functions $g$ such that $g=f$ almost everywhere.
In addition, the notation $\chi_A$ stands for the characteristic function of the set $A$.

My Question
Why is $F(\langle\chi_A\rangle)=\sum_k^{\infty}F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle)$?
I think this question shall be broken down to the following two questions:
First, I couldn't see why $\langle\chi_A\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle$ holds.
Second, I couldn't see why $F(\langle\chi_A\rangle)=\sum_k^{\infty}F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle)$? I am confused here because linearity is only defined for finite summation, right? Like $F(ax+by)=aF(x)+bF(y)$. But why can we extend it to an infinite sum?

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Since $F$ is linear, $\sum_{k = 1}^n F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle) = F(\left\langle \sum_{k = 1}^n \chi_{A_k}\right\rangle)$, so by continuity of $F$, $$\left\lvert F(\langle\chi_A\rangle) - \sum_{k = 1}^n F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle)\right\rvert \le \|F\| \cdot \|\chi_A - \sum_{k = 1}^n \chi_{A_k}\|_p \to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore $F(\langle\chi_A\rangle) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle)$.

Thank you so much for your answer. Just one quick question: Could you please explain why $$\left\lvert F(\langle\chi_A\rangle) - \sum_{k = 1}^n F(\langle\chi_{A_k}\rangle)\right\rvert \le |F| \cdot \left|\chi_A - \sum_{k = 1}^n \chi_{A_k}\right|_p$$ holds?

@Beerus recall that if $F$ is a continuous linear functional on a normed vector space $X$, then for all $x,y\in X$, $|F(x) - F(y)| = |F(x-y)| \le |F| \cdot |x-y|_X$.
